# Map scale will only double and halve in QGIS

Tags: qgis, scale

When I zoom in or out in QGIS, my scale will only halve or double respectively. This is the case whether I manually type the scale into the window at the bottom of the screen or select one of the set scale options. The scale automatically jumps to the nearest scale that is an exponent of base 2,256 (the smallest scale allowable for some reason), where the exponent is a multiple of 2. For example, if my scale is 144,447 and I type in or select 250,000, it automatically jumps to 288,895. This is occurring prior to adding any layers. I probably just have to uninstall/reinstall but though I would check here first.

Comment: If you go into the settings menu at top of QGIS window, then options-> Map Tools-> panning and zooming, you will find a setting for zoom factor. 2.0 seems to be the default setting. You can change this manually to any setting in increments of 0.1 down to 1.1. Zero will do nothing and I guess values less than zero will reverse the mouse wheel zoom control?

Comment: Unfortunately changing the zoom factor did not work. This has never been a problem for me before. It began during my last project, but now it is continuing on new QGIS files.

Answer (score 1):

It was the Tile Map Layers plugin. Works fine now.